# Bilinear interpolation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bilinear-interpolation

I am currently working on implementing spectrogram and the input to it are output from FFT. The results which I am getting is very pixelated. To make the output more smooth, I need to implement bilinear interpolation.

Is there any library or API readily available for it?

I found a function samplingLinear() in CoreImage which samples an image using bilinear interpolation. However, I need to interpolate the FFT data instead of an image.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.[Spectrogram_Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXKRc.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're displaying the data via OpenGL/CoreAnimation/UIImageView, you should do the interpolation there.

E.g. if you're displaying the data via a `CALayer`, you can set the `magnificationFilter` to `kCAFilterLinear`. If you're using OpenGL, you can set `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `GL_LINEAR`.